# ¿acontecimiental o acontecimental?

Tags: morfología

Soy hablante nativo del español, leo la palabra

> acontecimiental

¿Por qué no «acontecimental»?
¿Por qué me parece correcta la forma «acontecimental» si no digo «acontecimento» sino «acontecimiento»?
¿Puede alguien explicar la morfología de esta palabra o sugerirme alguna bibliografía?

Comment: Supongo que es mercadologia (marketing). Los franceses dicen: événement y événementiel.  Corespondería más o menos....https://gropius.com.es/marketing-de-acontecimientos/. Creo que es copiar el uso en francés. Sería bueno que nos diera más contexto. Palabras sueltas, respuestas devueltas. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los únicos sustantivos terminados en "-miento/a" de los cuales se me ocurren adjetivos derivados forman el adjetivo con el sufijo "-mental", por ejemplo:

- comportamiento => comportamental
- compartimiento => compartimental
- sentimiento => sentimental
- herramienta => herramental
- procedimiento => procedimental

No veo por qué debería ser diferente con "acontecimiento" si se desea crear un adjetivo a partir de ese sustantivo.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo. Pero no encuentro ninguna regala de derivación adjetival para -mental y en el libro que leo dice “acontecimiental”. Quiero diferir del editor con argumentos.

Comment: ¿acaso puedo concluir que es siempre así de los ejemplos que brindas? Yo creo que es -mental. Estaba seguro de que la palabra correcta es acontecimental hasta que la vi escrita de otro modo.

Comment: Si no te creen, pídeles que te den ejemplos de sustantivos terminados en "-miento" que formen el adjetivo con "-miental".

Comment: Normalmente la vocal diptongada se encuentra en la sílaba tónica, por lo cual se me hace torpe que esa termine en "-miental". Pero al buscarla en Google aparece unas veces en lo que me parecen varias obras. Puede ser un ejemplo de un término técnico que se fosilizó tal como es, o simplemente de una redacción descuidada.